# Add 1 static line to a csv with fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I making a csv like this:

```
$pulsos =  json_decode(json_encode($pulsos), true);
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ($pulsos as $line) {
    fputcsv($f, $line, ";");
}
fclose($f);
```

Where $pulsos is an Object. My csv is well generated, but I want to add some raw headers, I just want to add "a", "b", "c", etc. as the first line.

I tried something like

```
fputcsv($f, array('a','b','c'), ";");
```

But is not working. How can I do it?

Edit: removed some wrong line

Comment: `fputcsv($f, "sdas");` and `My csv is well generated`  I don't think that is true.

Comment: Sorry, that was part of my tryings

Comment: Strange, `fputcsv($f, array('a','b','c'), ";");` should work so long as it comes after the `fopen` call. What does it do when you say it does not work?

Comment: You do realise you can `foreach` over the properties of an object dont your? So there is no need to do all that json enc/decoding

Comment: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: Ok, I got it. I did it with: `fputcsv($f, array_keys($pulsos[0]),";"); `

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I did it with:

```
fputcsv($f, array_keys($pulsos[0]),";");
```